# Wrong .xsn file used as approval form

Tags: workflow, approval, xsn

I created a sharepoint 2010 approval workflow for a form which has multiple conditions. I've created the workflow in SPD, and it looks like this:

__

If Current Item:Backdated Period equals >0 Days & <=60 Days

Start Approval process on Current Item with Backdated 30 60:Approver Name

Else

Start Approval process on Current Item with Backdated 60 90:Approver Name

__

Backdated 30 60 and Backdated 60 90 are lists which contain approvers for each country.

My issue is with the form that opens when the approver clicks **Open This Task** for the **Backdated 30 60** approval process - the form doesn't contain the Approve and Reject buttons.

I've checked the content types in SPD and %complete and task status are not hidden, I've seen in another post that this should be the case, instead they are listed as optional.

I did try to edit the .xsn form with the missing buttons but I'm unable to link the Approve and Reject buttons to anything, after I add them. I tried using the *Submit Data* action rule but Approved or Rejected are not listed in the Data connection drop down, and I'm unable to add them from the sharepoint.

I'm sorry if this was posted before but I was unable to find a solution.

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Copy/paste the Approve and Reject buttons from the form that was working properly
2. Added a rule to each button - Add Rule > Action > Run these actions: Submit Data > In the Data connection drop down I didn't have Approved or Rejected listed so I clicked Add > Create a new connection to Submit data > To the hosting environment, such as ASP.NET page or a hosting application > named it Approved (and Rejected for the other button) > click Finish

I tested it and it works like a charm.

I hope this will help anyone.